# Java : how to notify objects ? (which patterns/...)

Tags: java, uml

A `CarManufacturer` creates a `Car` and stores it in a `ParkPlace` until the car is sold. The manufacturer must know, at a given time, where the unsold cars are.
For example, if *a* takes a car from a `ParkPlace`, the manufacturer must be "notified" (without defining what "notified" could be because I don't know what implementation could be better)

I feel like it's a classical problem where objects can be retrived manually. I could iterate over all the park places of all the factories all over the world and check which one is to the manufacturer. But it's inefficient. What is the standard way to solve this ?

Is it correct to create a class that acts as a wrapper between two aggregate classes ? Like a pointer of pointer in C.

Here my UML class diagram (in French: *Voiture* is *Car*, *Constructor* is *CarManufacturer*, *Fiche* is *Record*, *Place* is *ParkPlace*, *Rangee* is the *Row* in the parking):

[image: UML Class Diagram]

Constraints:

- The temporary "buffer" that the Manufacturer stores could be desynchronized. It's not written in UML but, the manufacturer can only own references to cars that he builds.
- It's not possible to store cars directly in manufacturer, because they don't have a place attribute (a car don't own a place), neither is it possible to store a Place inside manufacturer because when a car is moved, the constructor will also keep a reference to an empty place (or with a different car).

How to solve this, or is it a correct implementation ?

Comment: The word "notified" indicates a potential use for the [Observer design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer).

Comment: Your diagram seems incomplete and for a non-french user hard to interpret. Please make an (reduced, without attributes) English version showing all relations. Please know that shared aggregation has no defined semantics. You should remove it or explain the meaning in your context.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. A Constructeur knows his FicheVoitures (getStocks). For each FicheVoiture, he can get the corresponding Voiture (getVoiture) and Place (getPlace). So he knows where his cars are. Or do you want to know how to implement these operations? You are missing arrowheads pointing from FicheVoiture to Voiture and from FicheVoiture to Place.

Comment: I don't see a reason for `FicheVoiture` to exist. Seems you can simply connect `Voiture` with `Constructeur` and `Place`

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

It is not fully clear in your question, but I understand that:

- the parking is owned or managed by a party that is independent of the manufacturer.
- that this party makes the sales,
- this is why you want a notification.

#### Potential solutions

The classical solution to your problem is the [observer pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html): an `Observable` object informs one or several `Observer` that its state has changed. The notification is then implemented with a call to a method of the `Observer`, eventually passing to this method the reference of the invoking object (in case an observer follows several observables at once).

Another solution is to use an event driven architecture.  Events such as  moving a car from one place to the other, selling a car, etc... are published to one or several event queues by the object in charge, and an event processor does what is needed.  I your case you could imagine a CarEvent queue, in which every manufacturer would follow the events related to his cars.

#### What you need to do

Unfortunately, there are too many unclear issues in your model. For example:

- What happens with the `Record` when the `Car` is sold ?
- Why isn't the `Car` associated to the `Manufacturer` also ?
- Why doesn't the `ParkPlace` know about the `manufacturer`,  or at least the `Record` knows about the owning `Manufacturer` ?

So what you need to do is to clarify responsibilities in your design.  For example:

- Is the `ParkPlace` an `Observable` ? But who should be the `Observer` then:  the `Record` or the `Manufacturer` ?
- Or is the `Parkplace` only the way to find the `Record`, and the `Record` is the `Observable`, and the `Manufacturer` the `Observer` ?
- WHo is in charge of assigning a car (an its record) to a place ?  In your diagram both ParkPlace and Record have a function to assign to the other, so who is initiating ?

You also need to think about the aggregates:  do you really want to access directly from the `Place` aggregate to `Record` in another aggregate, without going through the aggregate root, which is Manufacturer ?

Once you have clarified all this, you need to rethink [navigability](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) along the associations.  This will help you to make the right implementation choices. Concretely, in your diagram it seems that the association from `Manufacturer` to `Record` is implemented as a list of `Records` in `Manufacturer`.  This way to implement the association implies a navigability from Manufacturer to Record, but not the other way round.